# How can I serialize an derived type pointer to interface type object in c++?

Tags: c++11, templates, interface, virtual, object-serialization

Interface * base_ptr1 = new Derived1();

Interface * base_ptr2 = new Derived2();

In theory I should have serialize() method in all classes but my interface type class does not have data members, only abstract virtual methods.

Comment: "my interface type class does not have data members" So what's the problem with that?

Comment: I used boost for serialization and boost::archive so I did not know about using istream and ostream

Comment: I tried to implement solution by reading this link https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html, so I couldn't find anything about interface type

Answer (score 0):

You could add pure `virtual` functions to do the serialization.

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual void read(std::istream& is) = 0;
    virtual void write(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Interface& i) {
    i.read(is);
    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Interface& i) {
    i.write(os);
    return os;
}
```

Now, the concrete classes only needs to implement `read` and `write` and the streaming operators implemented for `Interface` will work for them all.